# PECL Upload Progress - Compiled for Windows?

Tags: php, pecl

Could anyone be kind enough to point me to a link for the latest version (1.0.3.1) of the [PECL extension Upload Progress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress/1.0.3.1), compiled as a windows 32 bit DLL?

I've had a look on http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ but it doesn't seem to hold the latest version, I have the one from there and although its installed and running, its not returning data for me.

I know my code is good as I use a linux hosting server, and everything works - I just develop on Windows and its a little bit annoying not to be able to fully test a project without uploading.

Comment: Hehe, good luck with that. I had a heck of a time finding Windows dll files for PHP stuff before I saw the light and switched to Linux back in the day:)

Comment: Yeah, if and when my dev server dies it's getting Ubuntu, but I don't have the time or inclination to fix what isn't (completely) broken at the moment! (and I'm that much more comfortable with Windows).

Comment: I totally understand ... I was in the exact same position. I'd highly recommend installing Ubuntu on that laptop from 2004 you have laying around and easing into it. Might be painful at first but it makes development **SO MUCH SIMPLER** ... coming from Windows I couldn't believe it ... everything just worked. Sorry I can't offer a solution, but you might be able to convince someone to build the dll for you on a windows system.

Comment: If you've got the ram, just stuff ubuntu into a virtualbox VM. A non-graphic ubuntu environment doesn't need all that much ram anyways. you could run apache/php/mysql+ubuntu in 256meg pretty comfortably.

Comment: It turned out in the end that the site I was working on was going onto a shared host anyway, rather than on my dedicated server (so annoying when clients go ahead on a whim domains and hosting without asking for advice) - and their host of choice doesn't support upload progress so I ended up replacing the progress bar with a standard animated 'please wait' spinner anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link from anatoliy belsky:
[uploadprogress.dlls](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/uploadprogress/1.0.3.1/)

Comment: I haven't had need / chance to check if this version works but everything looks to be there so i'll accept this answer.

Comment: my first answer woohoo :p.. :)